# ng datepicker css customization and change the selected date from sqaure to circle

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-datepicker

i want to custom the calendar from this[enter image description here][1]
to this[enter image description here][2]

Can anyone please help me out. as i am not able to understand how to change selected day cell from sqaure to circle and select the range in same way.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRprR.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnQ9P.png

Comment: Which Calender library you are using? 
You need some changes in CSS files of Calender library. Mention the name of library or try inspecting the element and change style.

Comment: Hi muhammad, Thanks for helping. I am using NgbCalendar , yes i am left with two css customizations : 1) removing the navigation select from header 2) select the range including the space between two cells , but i am able to select only cells,

Comment: If its possible can you please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngbCalender loads inner style in your page when page loads in browser. If you inspect and in `Element` tab search for `.customer-day` class and append `border-radius : 50%` ... See image below , and for Range background there will be class `.range` change it according to your desire color and background shape.

[image]